# Spring Thymeleafs Template Engine error during template parsing

Tags: spring, flying-saucer, spring-thymeleaf

I can see there are a few question already asked in there, but still I can't find any solution to fix my issue. I am using Spring boot Thymeleafs Template Engine to parse value attribute with Spring Context. Then, I can process PDF generated with flying-saucer-pdf.

I can say the problem is because String is passed to parameter and it is not referent to html file.
Error description:

```
2022-10-11T16:45:58.209+0700 ERROR [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-2] Exception processing template "world-check-report": An error happened during template parsing (template: "applicationprocess/world-check-report.html")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "applicationprocess/world-check-report.html")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at com.aeon.webadmin.controller.AssessmentController.getWorldCheckStatus(AssessmentController.java:820) [classes/:1.3.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "applicationprocess/world-check-report.html" could not be resolved
at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ClassLoaderTemplateResource.reader(ClassLoaderTemplateResource.java:130) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

My Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/world-check-info")
public ObjResponseEntity<AmlApplyLoan> getWorldCheckStatus(@RequestBody String aln_id) {
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        AssessmentController assessmentController = new AssessmentController();
        
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("applicationprocess/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("message", "TESTING");
        
        //error here when parsing 
        String htmtContent = templateEngine.process("world-check-report", ctx);
        
        return ObjResponseFactory.success();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ObjResponseFactory.fail();
```

Template File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper" style="padding-left: 120px; font-family: sans-serif;">
        <h2 class="page_title" th:text="${message}"></h2>
        <h2>CASE REPORT</h2>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a configuration class but I still getting another error which is all the html files are applied with Template Engine. Actually, there is only a file that used ClassLoaderTemplateResolver and Template Engine parsed.

Comment: Can you add also the template file?

Comment: Hi @artiomi, template files is simple here:
 
<div class="content-wrapper" style="padding-left: 120px; font-family: sans-serif;">
  <h2 th:text="${message}"></h2>
</div>

Comment: There is no problem with your use of `TemplateEngine` and `Context`, what is the absolute path to `applicationprocess` folder?

Comment: @İsmailY. inside applicationprocess folder, there is html file that I use to write data 
template file: world-check-report.

templateEngine.process("world-check-report", ctx);

Comment: Your templates will be picked up automatically from `src/main/resources/applicationprocess`. What is the absolute path to the `applicationprocess` folder? So your folder is here?

Comment: Dear @İsmailY, there is too long to get back to you. I already solved the issue by manual create new class to receive data from back-end and pass to Thymleaf. 
Then I can execute PDF generated.

Thank you